# How to add aria-expanded and aria-controls to a v-select in Vue 2.6.14

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So, I'm working on the frontend for an old website that uses vue@2.6.14. My task is to make the website as accessible as possible. I identified that all the comboboxes on the website are not accessible as they don't have aria-controls and aria-expanded attributes to them. The code uses the v-select with: items property to make it work as a combobox.

When I look at the html of the rendered page, I can see that a div is generated with a role = "combobox" containing a few more elements, out of which is an input element. When I add 2 aria attributes to the v-select, those 2 attributes are not added to div with the combobox role (as I want it to be) but instead adds them to the input element, which is not ideal.

I'm completely stumped and can't figure how to solve this. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Vue code

```
<v-flex xs4 class="mr-4">
 <v-select>
  v-model="pSelection"
  :items="options"
  aria-label="Please select your operating system"
  single-line
 </v-select>
</v-flex>
```

I've tried to add those 2 aria attributes directly to the v-select but in html instead of adding it to the div with the role of combobox it adds to an input element.